# what is the correct behaviour when resizing the time axes of a live performance graph

Tags: graphs

I have a graph that shows live CPU and memory performance.
I am allowing the user to select the max number of minutes he wishes to see on the graph, so if he chooses 5 minutes he will only see the last 5 minutes of the graph.

you can see it here

[image]

my question is: if the user changes the the max number of minutes to display what should i do:

1. should I empty the graph and start from the current point in time
2. should I use the data in the graph and display as much of the gathered data as possible before adding a new value
3. any other implementation you know to be an industry standard

Answer (score 1):

Has the data changed? No? So keep showing it. Clearing it seems silly.

I'd simply show as much data as possible, anchored to the latest datapoint:

[image]

1. default size, perhaps you have older (grey) data cached.
2. when you shrink the graph, just move everything left, and you'll cull the excess.
3. if you expand the graph, and have cache, show that.
4. if you don't have cache, don't show anything. otherwise users could infer incorrect information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, implementing it this way makes a lot of sense